# Select friends from a MySQL database then select their details (Maybe with a join)

Tags: mysql, join

I have a MySQL table:

```
Friends
--------
fr_id
user_id_a
user_id_b
approval_status
---------
```

The basic logic behind it is that if User #1 sends a friend request to Friend #2 the table entry will look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
fr_id - user_id_a - user_id_b - approval_status
 1         1           2             no
------------------------------------------------
```

Now only when user approves the request, they will become friends.

To select all requests to User #1 I can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM friendship 
WHERE 
approved_status='no'
AND
(user_id_a = 1 OR user_id_b = 1)
```

The results will look like:

```
fr_id - user_id_a - user_id_b - approval_status
  1         1           2             no
```

How to distinguish if the current user is the one with `user_id_a` or `user_id_b` so I can use the other ID to pull their information from another table?

With the answer provided by @aweis

```
SELECT * , 
CASE WHEN user_id_a =3
THEN  'a'
ELSE  'b'
END AS UserIdColumn, 
CASE WHEN user_id_a =3
THEN user_id_b
ELSE user_id_a
END AS NotCurrentUserID
FROM fr_friendship
WHERE approved_status =  'yes'
AND (
user_id_a =3
OR user_id_b =3
)
```

i can select friends BUT im left with the secound part of the question is to JOIN then with another table to get user names of the friends...
i tried this but it gives me error..

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'NotCurrentUserID' in 'on clause'



SELECT f.*, p.username AS friend,

CASE WHEN user_id_a = 1 THEN 'a'
ELSE 'b'
END AS UserIdColumn,

CASE WHEN f.user_id_a = 1 THEN f.user_id_b
ELSE f.user_id_a
END AS NotCurrentUserID

FROM fr_friendship AS f
LEFT JOIN u_profile AS p ON p.user_id_login = NotCurrentUserID

WHERE 
f.approved_status = 'yes'
AND
(f.user_id_a = 1 OR f.user_id_b = 1)
```

EDIT: Solution

I managed to solve it....
I hope it helps someone:

```
SELECT a.friend_id, u.username
FROM
      ( SELECT CASE WHEN user_id_a = 1
                      THEN user_id_b 
                      ELSE user_id_a 
               END AS friend_id 
        FROM fr_friendship
        WHERE approved_status = 'yes' AND (user_id_a = 1 OR user_id_b = 1)
      ) AS a

LEFT JOIN u_profile AS u ON u.user_id_login = a.friend_id
```

Comment: Who's the initiator and who's the reciprocator - or does it not work like that?

Comment: thx for the reply @Strawberry actually it does not work that way. but logically its user_id_a is the initiator.. But thats not related to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `case` to determine what column the current user is in! In the code below I show both the column the current user is in, and I also have a second column containing all the ids of the not current user:

```
SELECT
*,
case when user_id_a = 1 then 'a'
else 'b'
end as UserIdColumn,
case when user_id_a = 1 then user_id_b
else user_id_a
end as NotCurrentUserID
FROM friendship 
WHERE 
approved_status = 'no'
AND
(user_id_a = 1 OR user_id_b = 1)
```

**Left vs inner join**

Consider the data structure and data below. In this example user id 1 is linked to user id 2, 3, and 4, but only user id 2 and 3 has profile.

```
create table fr_friendship
(
  fr_id int,
  user_id_a int,
  user_id_b int,
  approved_status varchar(3)
);

create table u_profile
(
  user_id_login int,
  username varchar(100)
);

insert into fr_friendship values (1, 1, 2, 'yes');
insert into fr_friendship values (2, 3, 1, 'yes');
insert into fr_friendship values (3, 1, 4, 'yes');

insert into u_profile values (2,'john doe');
insert into u_profile values (3, 'jane doe');
```

*Left join*

When using the left join:

```
SELECT a.friend_id, u.username
FROM
      ( SELECT CASE WHEN user_id_a = 1
                      THEN user_id_b 
                      ELSE user_id_a 
               END AS friend_id 
        FROM fr_friendship
        WHERE approved_status = 'yes' AND (user_id_a = 1 OR user_id_b = 1)
      ) AS a

LEFT JOIN u_profile AS u ON u.user_id_login = a.friend_id
```

All matches from the "inner select" is in the result set (the left part of the join), and matching profiles are join on, but if a user has no profile the right part contains pure null's. The result from above select is:

```
FRIEND_ID  USERNAME
2          john doe
3          jane doe
4          NULL
```

*Inner join*

When using inner join:

```
SELECT a.friend_id, u.username
FROM
      ( SELECT CASE WHEN user_id_a = 1
                      THEN user_id_b 
                      ELSE user_id_a 
               END AS friend_id 
        FROM fr_friendship
        WHERE approved_status = 'yes' AND (user_id_a = 1 OR user_id_b = 1)
      ) AS a

INNER JOIN u_profile AS u ON u.user_id_login = a.friend_id
```

The result set will only contain rows from friendship and profiles where there is a matching profile to the users. The result will be:

```
FRIEND_ID  USERNAME
2          john doe
3          jane doe
```

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) also has a good fast example of the different join types.

Comment: Thx @aweis it works fine... But it seem complex to Join with another table..?

Comment: Good to see that you worked your way to a solution. There was no info about the table to join with, so I didn't included that. Why are you left joining the profiles? That indicates that you can have user ids without profiles is that correct? in this case it is okay otherwise look at inner join

Comment: care to elaborate forther @aweis ...? By the way its just showing user friends list...

Comment: Hi, I have added an example with 4 users but only two that has a row in the profile table. Here the join type has a matter.